# ESP32 Cant receive any message in CAN bus line with any different device

Tags: embedded, esp32, can-bus

I am working on a CAN bus protocol with ESP32. I am using a library (https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-CAN) in here. Also, I am using MCP2551 as a CAN transceiver so I can communicate with two ESP32 successfully. But when I connect a CAN bus analyzer on the CAN bus line, the ESP32 program breaks and it doesn't work. Moreover, when I send a message with STM32 board on the line, ESP32 does not receive the message. I think there is a problem about bit timing. The sample point is not 70%-80% so it doesn't work with another CAN bus node, but I don't know how to configure this setting in the library. What should I do?

My system is the receiver is ESP32, transmitter is CAN bus analyzer. ESP32 does not receive any message from analyzer or any device but it can communicate another ESP32 successfully.

Comment: Did you check terminating resistor present on bus for both sides? Try value 120,1K or 10k Ohm. Depends on cable's impedance.

Answer (score 0):

Misc advice:

- CAN bus analyzers are often set in passive mode where they don't ACK any incoming messages. That will not work if there is only one other node on the bus, the ESP32. In that case you either have to set the CAN analyzer to active so that it sends ACK, or add an additional node to the bus.
- Which baudrate are you using and what do you see on the bus? Are there error frames? That is, sequences of 6 high or low bits with the expected baudrate. For example at 250kbps you will see pulses of 1/250k * 6 = 24us if there are error frames. Perhaps needless to say, an oscilloscope is mandatory equipment when working with embedded systems.
- Apart from having the correct baudrate, bit timing and sample points could mess things up if you are using exotic settings. For most baudrates the recommended sample point is at 87.5% of a bit length. I don't understand what you mean with "the sample point is not 70%-80%"... well, what is it then, and how do you know that if you don't know how to configure the library?

Comment: Hello, Firstly, When I work on stm32 and canbus analyzer it works succesfully and I can adjust my can bus parameter settings in stm32 easily. My baudrate is 500kbps for every node  and my sample point is about %76 I mean BS1/BS1+BS2 is %70 but I cannot adjust canbus bit timing parameters in ESP32 and I just assumed that the sample point is not %70-%80 in ESP32. In summarize I dont know how to configure bit timing parameters in that library on ESP32. The problem is about bit timing probabily so  could you help me for configuring bit timing parameters in this library ?

Comment: @mazers I have never used ESP32 nor whatever CAN controller it uses. This is best discussed in general terms as per the C standard. Each bit is divided into time quanta and various segments of the bit are given different names. All segments before the sample point should ideally add up to 87.5% of the total bit length. Anyway, that's not the first thing you should look at. Start with probing the CANH/CANL lines with your scope, then take it from there. If there are error frames, bit timing is less likely to be the culprit.